# Correct match using RegEx but it should work without substitution

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have [`<autorpodpis>([^;,<\n\r]*?)\s*[;,<\n\r]`](https://regex101.com/r/zZ2zF0/7) to catch everything inside

```
<autorpodpis>_this_is_an_example_of_what_I'd_like_to_match<
```

If there is a space, a colon (;) or a semicolon (;) or a space before a colon or a semicolon, my RegEx catches everything but including these characters – see my link. It works as it is expected to.

Overall, the RegEx works fine with substitution `\1` (or in AutoHotKey I use – `$1`). But I'd like match without using substitution.

Comment: Try `pos := RegExMatch(input, "<autorpodpis>(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*)", Res)  ` and the result should be in `Res[1]`.

Comment: Yes, it does the trick but it uses substitution – `Res[1]` is a form of it. Any chance of getting only `Res`?

Comment: Do you mix the terms *substitution* with *capturing*? Try `pos := RegExMatch(input, "(?<=<autorpodpis>)\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*", Res)`

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks for pointing to the difference. **Addition:** So your answer is correct as is mine initial solution. I see you have edited you answer. Please supply it as an answer. What would be _best_ (say, fastest, superior): your first answer or your second? I suppose that my initial RegEx is worst than yours.

Comment: Yes, I guess, if you are not interested in an answer with a lookbehind, you can remove your post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know little about RegEx in general and  in lookbehind in particular. I'm interested in a good solution. I think that yours is a good one and deserves to be provided as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mix the terms *substitution* (regex based replacement operation) and *capturing* (storing a part of the matched value captured with a part of a pattern enclosed with a pair of unescaped parentheses inside a numbered or named stack).

If you want to just match a substring in specific context without capturing any subvalues, you might consider using [*lookarounds*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (lookbehind or lookahead).

In your case, since you need to match a string *after* some known string, you need a *lookbehind*. A lookbehind *tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there*.

So, you could use

```
pos := RegExMatch(input, "(?<=<autorpodpis>)\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*", Res)
```

So, the `Res` should have `WOJCIECH ZAŁUSKA` if you supply `<autorpodpis>WOJCIECH ZAŁUSKA</autorpodpis>` as input.

Explanation:

- `(?<=<autorpodpis>)` - check if there is `<autorpodpis>` right before the currently tested location. If there is none, fail this match, go on to the next location in string
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ Unicode letters
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)*` - 0+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ Unicode letters.

However, in most cases, and always in cases like this **when the pattern in the lookbehind is known, the lookbehind is unanchored (say, when it is the first subpattern in the pattern) and you do not need overlapping matches**, use *capturing*.

The version with [**capturing**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in place:

```
pos := RegExMatch(input, "<autorpodpis>(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*)", Res)
```

And then `Res[1]` will hold the `WOJCIECH ZAŁUSKA` value. Capturing is in most cases (96%) faster.

Now, your regex - `<autorpodpis>([^;,<\n\r]*?)\s*[;,<\n\r]` - is not efficient as the `[^;,<\n\r]` also matches `\s` and `\s` matches `[;,<\n\r]`. My regex is *linear*, each subsequent subpattern does not match the previous one.