# RegEx: Allow for a single dot after one possible letter

Tags: regex, unicode

Thanks to the [answer by Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449589/2657875) and its detailed discussion I have a RegEx [`(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/dK8pK8/1) that catches characters (also Unicode) up to e.g. a dot (.) and a semicolon (;). But I'd like to catch a dot only if there is a single character (it could be unicode one) before it and there are some characters after it. Let me give you some examples. RegEx correctly catches e.g.:

```
WOJCIECH T ZAŁUSKA
WOJCIECH ZAŁUSKA
WOJCIECH Ted ZAŁUSKA
```

But it fails to catch correctly:

```
WOJCIECH T. ZAŁUSKA
```

I get everything but the dot (WOJCIECH T ZAŁUSKA) and I'd like to catch this dot too.

So, I'd like to catch strings like the one above. More examples of what I need:

```
Ted J. Knox
Chris Jay J. Nick
```

In strings where there are multiple dotes only first one should be taken into account. Let me give you an example of what I do not like to catch. Consider the following string:

```
WOJCIECH T. ZAŁUSKA. Adam
```

Only `WOJCIECH T. ZAŁUSKA` should be caught. I tried `(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+\.)*)` but it catches more than one dot and have more shortcomings.

Comment: Are these strings standalone? Or in some marked up text?

Comment: Well, if the dot can come only after the second "word", use [`\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+\.)?(?:\s+\p{L}+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/bN6oZ9/1).

Comment: Dear @WiktorStribiżew They are standalone: one string = one RegEx. Your RegEx is as perfect as always. I cannot tell how grateful I am for your continuous help.

Comment: `(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}\.)*)|((\.\s).*$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dot can come only after the second "word", use

```
\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}\.)?(?:\s+\p{L}+)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN6oZ9/2)

The pattern will match:

- `\p{L}+` - 1 or more letters
- `(?:\s+\p{L}\.)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of 1+ whitespace + 1 letter + a dot
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+)+` - 1+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces + 1 or more letters

Comment: what's the difference between `\h` and `\s`?

Comment: `\h` stands for horizontal whitespace (it does not match newlines and carriage returns) while `\s` matches all whitespace. I usually use `\h` at the online testers so as not to overflow to the next line (as lines are usually tested there, not whole strings).

Comment: hmm.. cool.. strange because when I change the expression to use \s instead, it doesn't highlight the same thing as \h.

Comment: by the way, shouldn't `Chris Jay J. Nick` catch `Chris Jay J.` ?

Comment: I have an idea for those cases: [`(?<!\.\h)\b\p{L}+(?:(?:\h+\p{L}+)*(?:\h+\p{L}\.)(?:\h+\p{L}+)*|(?:\h+\p{L}+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bN6oZ9/3). Not sure it will work well if the strings appear in larger contexts. If the `WOJCIECH T. ZAŁUSKA. Adam` should not be matched at all and the strings are tested individually, then, [`^\p{L}+(?:(?:\h+\p{L}+)*(?:\h+\p{L}\.)(?:\h+\p{L}+)*|(?:\h+\p{L}+)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bN6oZ9/4) can be used. But: if `WOJCIECH T. ZAŁUSKA` must be matched there,and `Adam` should not,`^\p{L}+(?:(?:\h+\p{L}+)*(?:\h+\p{L}\.)(?:\h+\p{L}+)*|(?:\h+\p{L}+)*)` is ok.